# Removing variables from this SQL query (Sub-queries help)

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I did a query like this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(Prop1) AS CurrentAmount,

@prop1:= Prop1,
@prop2:= Prop2,
@prop3:= Prop3,
@prop4:= Prop4,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM myTable WHERE Prop1=@prop1 AND Prop2=@prop2 AND Prop3=@prop3 AND Prop4=@prop4 GROUP BY Prop1) AS TotalAmount


FROM myTable
WHERE Target = 1876
GROUP BY Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Prop4;
```

Notice the aliased columns named CurrentAmount and TotalAmount.
I pretend they calculate the amount of articles assigned Target=1876 in comparison with the amount of other similar articles in the table (others which share the same values for Prop1-4 but assigned to other targets).

However. I do not like the way of using @variables in the normal columns. Would be another way to calculate this, where TotalAmount would be completely self-contained in a subquery?

It's very important **keeping** that **WHERE Target = 1876**. Everything else may be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
COUNT(A.Prop1) AS CurrentAmount
 (SELECT COUNT(B.ID) FROM myTable B WHERE 
 A.Prop1=B.Prop1 AND A.Prop2=B.Prop2 AND 
 A.Prop3=B.Prop3 AND A.Prop4=B.Prop4 GROUP BY 
 B.Prop1) AS TotalAmount
FROM myTable A
WHERE Target = 1876
GROUP BY A.Prop1, A.Prop2, A.Prop3, A.Prop4;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. It was exactly what I was looking for! :)